# Getting error while run angular/compiler-cli command

Tags: angular

Try to run following command for implement AOT in angular2

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli typescript@next @angular/platform-server @angular/compiler
```

but gives me error, also can you give me step by step how i compile application for AOT

Also how i can run the node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
command

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@2.1.0-dev.20161012 invalid
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@0.3.0 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.2 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Follow the steps from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by unmet dependencies. You should install a newer version of angular2. 
After that, run the command again.
Browse root path of your project and run the command below.

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

You can get a detailed explanation from [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html).